# Scatter chart padding increases when there is data

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am working on multiple charts (scatter chart and bar chart) and I want to combine them to look like 1, but I am having some problems with scatter chart padding for x axis when dataset is not empty.

Scatter chart config:

```
        scales: {
          x: {
            display: true,
            position: 'bottom',
            min: 0,
            max: 20,
            grid: {
              display: true,
            },
            ticks: {
              align: 'inner',
              stepSize: 5,
              padding: 0,
              mirror: true,
            },
          },
          y: {
            display: false,
          },
        },
```

Bar chart config:

```
        scales: {
          x: {
            position: 'bottom',
            display: true,
            stacked: true,
            border: {
              display: false,
            },
            min: 0,
            max: 20,
            ticks: {
              align: 'inner',
              stepSize: 5,
              padding: -18,
              mirror: true,
            },
          },
          y: {
            display: false,
            stacked: true,
          },
        },
```

[As you can see it looks alright when there is no dots in scatter chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVDmO.png)

[And when there are dots some padding appears for beginning and the end.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti4o7.png)

Any ideas how I could fix this? Your ideas are really appreciated!

**EDIT:** You can find full code example here - [Code Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nc3sdn?file=src%2Fscatter-chart%2Fscatter-chart.component.ts)

Comment: I don't see any padding, the only difference appears to be a change in bar data, which contains a new red stripe from 0 to 1 and a shorter one from 11 to 15, instead of 10 to 15. In any case, there is too little information, I don't understand how you have two visible x axes, have you overlapped them by matching the negative padding? Please post a runnable version of your code that we can debug (not necessarily your full code, just a runnable [minimal adaptation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that creates your chart). Cheers!

Comment: @kikon thanks for your reply! Here you can find a runnable version - [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nc3sdn?file=src%2Fmain.ts). Let me know if anything else is missing, appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi, that's great, but I still don't see what is the problem, I just see no difference in layout with scatter data or with no scatter data, can you please explain?

Comment: Do you want the scatter points to be placed exactly on the axis?

Comment: As you can see bar and scatter chart shares the same min and max, so those charts should represent the same data, but when there are scatter points, scatter chart itself shrinks a bit and some spacing appears in the front and at the end. It should be straight horizontal line for all 3 charts at the beginning and at the end.

[Here you can see it](https://ibb.co/7Xf5cgx)
There is no straight horizontal line between all of the charts and I would like it to start at the same position and end at the same position. I hope it's more clear now. Thanks @kikon !

Comment: I'm really sorry, I hope someone else will see it. It might be the low resolution of my monitor or the operating system... I [forked the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cg7gkx?file=src%2Fscatter-chart%2Fscatter-chart.component.ts) to set the background colors of the `divs` and then increased their height so I can see the grid lines and everything seems perfectly aligned to me.

Comment: But the dot at {x: 0, y: 0} is cut into a half, does it look right for you? It is really strange - [screenshot](https://ibb.co/4RHyTGf)

Comment: Funnily, I just opened  my stackblitz  to check something about the point cut in half, and now I see a shift of a few pixels to the right in the top area where the dots are (which was not there the other day), while the first point is still cut in half. I'll try to look into it, if I can find the cause, now that I get the problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out what is the cause of your misalignment: a scatter
chart that has points, will by default leave space to the left and to the right such that a
point at  `x = min` or at `x = max` will fit to the canvas without being cut;
that means that the padding you observed is equal to point properties
`pointRadius + borderWidth`. You can find
the computation of that space in the source code, in the
function `getMaxOverflow`,
[for scatter](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v4.4.2/src/controllers/controller.scatter.js#L156)
and [for bar](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v4.4.2/src/controllers/controller.bar.js#L357).

Now, in order to actually use that space, one has to also set
the [`clip`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#general)
option to the same value (if `pointRadius` is 4, `borderWidth` default 1,
set `clip: 5`).

To **disable that padding** computation, you may set
`options.layout.autoPadding` to `false` ([docs link](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html#layout)).

This has the drawback that points at extreme x values will be cut in half.

With that, there still remain 3 pixels of padding in the scatter, which I
traced to the negative padding of the x axis ticks; although it is vertical
padding, setting `padding: -1` will completely remove the left and right
spaces.

To resume, to remove the padding:

- set `options.layout.autoPadding` to `false`
- set `options.scales.x.ticks.padding` to `-1`

---

Another approach that can be used is to *assume* the point padding -
and set it explicitly to both charts (with or without data):

```js
   options: {
      layout: {
         padding: {
            left: 5,
            right: 5,
            top: ....
         }
      },
      clip: { // for scatter only 
         left: 5,
         right: 5,  
         top: 0,
         bottom: 0 
      }, 
      // ... other options
   }
```

That will ensure the two charts are aligned in any case and that points
at `x = 0` and `x = 20` are not cut. Also, it allows for a better solution
for the bar chart ticks with large negative padding.

---

Going further, that kind of alignment will always remain fragile;
it would be safer if you let chart.js to manage the arrangement
in a [stacked](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scales/stacked.html)
chart, and use only one x axis, if the two plots
have the same scaling on x, which will ensure they are aligned.

Here's a sketch of that with your data:

```js
const config = {
    data: {
        labels: ['Data1'],
        datasets:[{
            type: 'bar',
            barThickness: 4,
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: [5],
            backgroundColor: ['green'],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ['green'],
        },
        {
            type: 'bar',
            barThickness: 4,
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: [10],
            backgroundColor: ['orange'],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ['orange'],
        },
        {
            type: 'bar',
            barThickness: 4,
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: [5],
            backgroundColor: ['red'],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ['red'],
        },

        {
            type: 'scatter',
            data: [
                {x: 15, y: 0},
                {x: 10, y: 0},
                {x: 5, y: 0},
                {x: 4, y: 0},
                {x: 3, y: 0},
                {x: 2, y: 0},
                {x: 1, y: 0},
                {x: 0, y: 0}
            ],
            yAxisID: 'y2',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'blue',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'blue',
            pointRadius: 4,
            pointHoverRadius: 4,
            showLine: false,
            pointHitRadius: 4,
            pointStyle: 'circle',
            borderColor: 'gray',
        }]
    },
    options: {
        animation: false,
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        layout: {
            //autoPadding: false, // for zero left-right space
        },
        clip: { left: 5, top: 0, right: 4, bottom: 0 },
        interaction: {
            mode: 'nearest',
            axis: 'xy',
        },
        indexAxis: 'y',
        scales: {
            x: {
                display: true,
                border: { width: 0 },
                min: 0,
                max: 20,
                grid: {
                    display: true,
                    tickLength: 1
                },
                ticks: {
                    display: true,
                    align: 'inner',
                    stepSize: 5,
                    padding: -1,
                },
                stacked: true
            },
            y: {
                display: false,
                stacked: true,
                stack: "A"
            },
            y2: {
                display: false,
                stacked: true,
                stack: "A"
            },
        },
        events: ['click'],
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false,
            },
            title: {
                display: false,
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false,
            },
        },
    },
};

new Chart(document.querySelector('#chart1'), config);
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 48px">
    <canvas id="chart1" style="background-color:rgba(192, 192, 255, 0.7)">
    </canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.2/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
```